# Cross browser Printing using Canvas like Firefox(mozPrintCallback)

Tags: html, google-chrome, internet-explorer, firefox, safari

Is there any cross browser solution to draw the printing content directly a canvas while printing like Firefox(mozPrintCallback) ?

If not Is their any supported solution for the major browsers: like Chrome, Firefox, Safari and IE